# How to console log the answer instead of whole function (Javascript, ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm working on some ES6 code, and I want to console.log or document.write the answer to my function. When I attempt to do this, it writes the entire function instead. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
const stats = {
  max: 56.78,
  standard_deviation: 4.34,
  median: 34.54,
  mode: 23.87,
  min: -0.75,
  average: 35.85
};

const half = ({max, min}) => (max+min) / 2.0; 

document.write(half)
```

Comment: __Call__ the function.

Comment: `half` is a function; you haven't invoked it. Are you familiar with JavaScript's invocation syntax? `half(stats)`, perhaps? (Tangential; why are you using `document.write()`? This has not been considered best practice for quite some time now.)

Comment: Use `()` to invoke function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to invoke the function using parenthesis (and pass the `stats` object as a parameter):

```
const stats = {
 max: 56.78,
 standard_deviation: 4.34,
 median: 34.54,
 mode: 23.87,
 min: -0.75,
 average: 35.85
};

const half = ({max, min}) => (max+min) / 2.0; 

document.write(half(stats))
```